# Plot spectrum of a wave as in Audacity

Tags: python, audio, fft, frequency, spectrum

I would like to plot frequency graphs similar to the ones that Audacity can draw:

[image: Audacity frequency PNG]

I did not find a software to do that (in command line) so I started to play with python to do it, using the specgram function. 
As I am not able to redo such a graph (the purple one from audacity), I was wondering if someone know exactly what Audacity is plotting, waht it means, and is there any pseudo-code somewhere? I have less than basic knowledge in audio processing, but if someone guides me on that part, I think I can code any suggestion/pseudo code/procedure.
Right now, I'm here, plotting something like this which is roughly what I have seen everywhere so far.

[image: My amplitude and freq graphs PNG]

```
> pxx, freqs, bins, _ = plt.specgram(y, NFFT=s, Fs=rate, noverlap=0,
                                        cmap=plt.cm.binary, sides='onesided',
                                        window=signal.blackmanharris(s),
                                        scale_by_freq=True,
                                        mode='magnitude')
plot(freqs, numpy.log10(pxx.max(axis=1)))
```

I don't understand how can I get these "decrease" of dB vs. frequency which I can see on any audio WAV with Audacity

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see Audacity plots the magnitude spectrum, i.e. the absolute value of the [fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform) of the first 2048 samples. You plot the maximum amplitude in all time chunks relating to each frequency bin of the [short time fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-time_Fourier_transform).

Maybe this fits your needs:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

y = y[0:2048] * signal.blackmanharris(2048)
X_amp = np.abs(np.fft.rfft(y))
X_db = 20 * np.log10(X_amp)
freqs = np.fft.rfftfreq(2048, 1/rate)
plt.plot(freqs, X_db)
```

**EDIT:**

Oh I found this page in the [Audacity manual](http://manual.audacityteam.org/o/man/plot_spectrum.html). So `plt.specgram` should be fine to imitate Audacity, just take `np.average(pxx, axis=1)`. The manual does not say what hop size is used... maybe try to set the `noverlap`-parameter to `s/2`. (A common choice.)

Comment: Why the first 2048 samples? Shouldn't all samples be calculated fft?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I was close but you found it.
Finally the code is quite simple:

```
pxx, freqs, bins, _ = plt.specgram(y, NFFT=s, Fs=rate, noverlap=0,
                                   cmap=plt.cm.binary, sides='onesided',
                                   window=signal.blackmanharris(s),
                                   scale_by_freq=True,
                                   mode='magnitude')
plot(freqs, 20 * log10(mean(pxx, axis=1)), 'g')
```

And, except the y-axis unit, I'm almost one pixel accurate against audacity:

[Final plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R43Vk.png)